# Tailwind sometimes not applying styles to Wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm facing an issue with tailwindcss on my wordpress project. I made all the configuration and sometimes tailwind is applying styles but when i try it next day it wont work. Basically Tailwind is compiling their classes to my output.css file but then wordpress does not recognize the classes in the front. Note that this happens some times.

I'm showing my config there:[Tailwind Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvx8M.png).Tailwind config in functions.php:[Tailwind script in functions.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGQJY.png). And i'm attaching there two example, and as you can see in first screenshot i'm writing tailwind class pl-16 but isnt working: [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pItWn.png).But in my output tailwind already compiled the class.[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P71Ea.png)

Comment: Maybe caching issue - try to clear it plus add version for styles (4th parameter for `wp_enqueue_style` - set `time()` for example instead of `null`)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka there was no problem with caching but the problem was as you said, with version, i just replaced `null` with `time()` and that helped me to fix my issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please be aware its a temporary fix. It is better to replace `time()` with an actual version or hash to allow caching on production. During development it is ok to left `time()`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka alright, I'll see about that, thank you very much!